# SpringBoot jar project + swaggerUI + chef + dynamic variables

Tags: dynamic, spring-boot, chef-infra, swagger, swagger-ui

I have a SpringBoot application that uses Swagger for the API doc and Swagger-UI for rendering it.

Before using the any of the endpoints from swagger-ui I need to retrieve a bearer token and for this a clientID and an authorize endpoint are used

I have 2 different environment where both the clientID and the authorize endpoint are different.

I'm using chef to handle the deployment of my app (which is a JAR started as java -jar myapi.jar) which builds a different application.properties for each environment but because the clientID and auth url are in the swagger-ui's index.html and that thee files are INSIDE the jar I don't know how to use chef to replace these values at deploy time.

Is there a way I can passed these values somehow? Or the only solution is to not have a JAR but an exploded jar ?

TLDR: I want to be able replace values in the index.html depending on the environement

Comment: That's a little unclear for me, but I think you should be able to craft some ruby code to unzip in memory, get the values and set them as node attribute on the UI server, and then access this node attributes from the client...

Answer (score 0):

I;m not aware of anything in springboot/swagger that let you pass values to the static files (aka ${clientId} from your index.html)

What you could do though is having chef template (a simple json file can be enough) containing

```
{
 "clientID":..
 "authUrl: ..
}
```

That you make chef write in the same directory where your index.html is. And in your index.html write some javascript to load that file.